# AWS ElastiCache SSL secured cluster + Spring Data Redis + Lettuce "Redis health check failed"

Tags: ssl, spring-data-redis, amazon-elasticache, redis-cluster, lettuce

We are trying to secure our ElastiCache cluster to Spring Boot traffic by enabling SSL encryption.
Spring Boot app successfully starts, but when it tries to register on Eureka and Spring Boot Admin `RedisHealthIndicator` fails with an exception:

```
2020-02-28 12:31:32.742   WARN [app,,,] 8894 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.b.a.redis.RedisHealthIndicator       :      Redis health check failed     

org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Unable to connect to Redis; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisException: Cannot retrieve initial cluster partitions from initial URIs [RedisURI [host='my-cluster-url.amazonaws.com', port=6379]]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$SharedConnection.getNativeConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1111)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$SharedConnection.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1084)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.getClusterConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:363)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.doGetConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:132)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.getConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:95)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.getConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.redis.RedisHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(RedisHealthIndicator.java:56)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:84)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.CompositeHealthIndicator.health(CompositeHealthIndicator.java:98)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.CompositeHealthIndicator.health(CompositeHealthIndicator.java:98)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.health(HealthEndpoint.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension.health(HealthEndpointWebExtension.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.invoke.reflect.ReflectiveOperationInvoker.invoke(ReflectiveOperationInvoker.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.AbstractDiscoveredOperation.invoke(AbstractDiscoveredOperation.java:61)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$ServletWebOperationAdapter.handle(AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.java:294)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.java:355)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.servlet.CompositeHandlerAdapter.handle(CompositeHandlerAdapter.java:58)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:209)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisException: Cannot retrieve initial cluster partitions from initial URIs [RedisURI [host='my-cluster-urlamazonaws.com', port=6379]]
    at io.lettuce.core.cluster.RedisClusterClient.loadPartitions(RedisClusterClient.java:865)
    at io.lettuce.core.cluster.RedisClusterClient.initializePartitions(RedisClusterClient.java:819)
    at io.lettuce.core.cluster.RedisClusterClient.connect(RedisClusterClient.java:345)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.ClusterConnectionProvider.getConnection(ClusterConnectionProvider.java:85)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$SharedConnection.getNativeConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1104)
    ... 62 common frames omitted
Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandInterruptedException: Command interrupted
    at io.lettuce.core.cluster.topology.ClusterTopologyRefresh.loadViews(ClusterTopologyRefresh.java:109)
    at io.lettuce.core.cluster.RedisClusterClient.doLoadPartitions(RedisClusterClient.java:871)
    at io.lettuce.core.cluster.RedisClusterClient.loadPartitions(RedisClusterClient.java:844)
    ... 66 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: null
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:347)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1915)
    at io.lettuce.core.cluster.topology.RefreshFutures.awaitAll(RefreshFutures.java:51)
    at io.lettuce.core.cluster.topology.AsyncConnections.get(AsyncConnections.java:80)
    at io.lettuce.core.cluster.topology.ClusterTopologyRefresh.loadViews(ClusterTopologyRefresh.java:73)
    ... 68 common frames omitted
```

**Setup:**

- Spring Boot version 2.1.4.RELEASE
- ElastiCache - Redis 5.0.3

**Workflow:**

- App starts and connects to ElastiCache cluster

```
2020-02-28 12:29:31.786  DEBUG [app,,,] 8894 --- [nfoReplicator-0] io.lettuce.core.RedisClient              :      Connecting to Redis at my-cluster-url.amazonaws.com:6379  
2020-02-28 12:29:32.633  DEBUG [app,,,] 8894 --- [ioEventLoop-8-1] io.lettuce.core.RedisClient              :      Connecting to Redis at my-cluster-url.amazonaws.com:6379: Success
```

- After some time 10-20s `Redis health check failed` warning is logged and App is marked as dead in Eureka even though it still tries to reconnect to ElastiCache and is able to see the cluster.

```
2020-02-28 12:31:48.159  DEBUG [app,,,] 30409 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.d.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils    :      Opening RedisConnection     
2020-02-28 12:31:48.162  DEBUG [app,,,] 30409 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] i.l.c.c.PooledClusterConnectionProvider  :      getConnection(WRITE, my-cluster-url.amazonaws.com, 6379)         
2020-02-28 12:31:48.165  DEBUG [app,,,] 30409 --- [ioEventLoop-9-1] i.l.core.protocol.RedisStateMachine      :      Decoded LatencyMeteredCommand [type=CLUSTER, output=StatusOutput [output=cluster_state:ok
cluster_slots_assigned:16384
cluster_slots_ok:16384
cluster_slots_pfail:0
cluster_slots_fail:0
cluster_known_nodes:4
cluster_size:2
cluster_current_epoch:3
cluster_my_epoch:3
cluster_stats_messages_ping_sent:2468227
cluster_stats_messages_pong_sent:2527673
cluster_stats_messages_meet_sent:3
cluster_stats_messages_sent:4995903
cluster_stats_messages_ping_received:2527667
cluster_stats_messages_pong_received:2468229
cluster_stats_messages_meet_received:3
cluster_stats_messages_fail_received:1
cluster_stats_messages_received:4995900
, error='null'], commandType=io.lettuce.core.protocol.AsyncCommand], empty stack: true
```

**Configuration:**

```
LettuceClientConfiguration lettuceClientConfiguration = LettuceClientConfiguration.builder().useSsl().disablePeerVerification().build();

return new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisClusterConfiguration, lettuceClientConfiguration);
```

Tried to set `.startTls()` - didn't helped.
Tried to set `.pingBeforeActivateConnection(true)` - didn't helped.

I guess problem is inside `spring-boot-actuator` it self, so one of possible solutions could be to try to override [RedisHealthIndicator](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/redis/RedisHealthIndicator.java).

Answer (score 0):

After adding password on ElastiCache cluster and configuring Lettuce driver to make AUTH call instead of NO_AUTH connection was established between ElastiCache and Spring application.

Comment: Hi how did you make the driver to make AUTH calls?